# Java issue NoClassDefFound javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart

Tags: java, soap

I have been given a java app to modify with the following:

```
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
```

But When I run it from cmd it throws the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/axis/SOAPP art

It seems to find the other imports without issue. Does 'NoClassDefFound' mean the class itself wasn't found? If so how can I check it is there and replace it if not? (I am using Eclipse)

**Update:** Okay I have found the class in 'JRE System Library>rt.jar>javax.xml.soap>SOAPPart.class' So if the class is there why do I get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to choose Export> 'Runnable JAR file' in eclipse instead of 'JAR file'